# Click button and load navigation controller

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationcontroller

A very simple question: My iPhone app has a button in MainWindow.xib. When I press that button a new view should load. That view will contain a nice navigation controller. How can I do that?

All the information I've found is about apps that start directly from a navigation controller. I need to load the nav controller after a button click.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go about this is to simply hide the navigation bar in your root controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  ...
  if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  ...
}
```

That way, you have a nice, clean root controller with no navigation bar in the way.

When you click on a button in your root controller, you simply push in a new view and un-hide the navigation bar:

```
- (IBAction) pushAnotherView:(id)sender {
  AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
  if ([self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  [anotherViewController release];
}
```

If you have some notification or other action that brings you back to the root view controller, just hide the notification bar again:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```